# How do I write a C# method that will accept an injected dependency of unknown type?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

### Background

I have a couple of utility methods I would like to add to a solution on which I am working and  use of dependency injection would open many more potential uses of said methods.

I am using C#, .NET 4

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish (this is *just* an example):

```
public static void PerformanceTest(Func<???> func, int iterations)
{
    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
      var x = func();
    }
    stopWatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

What I have done here is create a method to test the performance of certain elements of my code when debugging.  Here is an example of how you would use it:

```
Utilities.PerformanceTest(someObject.SomeCustomExtensionMethod(),1000000);
```

### Question

The "PerformanceTest" method expects to be passed (injected) a function of known type.  But what if I want "PerformanceTest" to allow injection of various functions that return various types?  How do I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can't it be just generic?

```
public static void PerformanceTest<T>(Func<T> func, int iterations)
{
    var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        T x = func();
    }
    stopWatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Also if you don't care of what type is the argument, you can pass `Func<object>`, can't you?

Comment: Looks great!  I am struggling with how to call the method.  I will continue working on that by myself, but if you could show me I would be most grateful.  Thanks!

Comment: This will definitelly work, but only in case when func does not have any parameters.

Comment: You could have multiple overrides like `public static void PerformanceTests<T,T2>(Func<T, T2>func, int iterations)`...

Comment: `Utilities.PerformanceTest<T>(() => someObject.SomeCustomExtensionMethod(),1000000);`

Comment: A few more minute before I can accept your answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

I would change your PerformanceTest method to this:

```
public static void PerformanceTest(Action func, int iterations)
```

End than call:

```
Utilities.PerformanceTest(() => someObject.SomeCustomExtensionMethod(),1000000);
```

This will probably increase the time, because of lambda expression, but I can´t say how or if this is even important,

Answer (score 2):

Use generics:

```
public static void PerformanceTest<T>(Func<T> func, int iterations)
{
    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
      var x = func();
    }
    stopWatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```